# SSH proxy and remote port?

Tags: ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

Sample :

`[[Server]]` has two interfaces : iface1 and iface2 ;

- iface1 only listens SSH
- iface2 only listens HTTPS (my target)

Only `[[SSHProxy]]` is authorized to connect to `[[Server]]:22`

diagram :

```
:iface2(listen 443) [[Server]] :iface1(listen 22) <-----> [[SSHProxy]] :iface1(listen 22) <-----> [[MyStation]]
```

QUESTION ==> How to forward locally `[[Server]]:iface2(443)` on `[[MyStation]]` in 1 ti in ssh_config, with `nc` or `"-w"` option in SSH ??

Actually I do it in two times :

1. From [[MyStation]] : `ssh user@[[SSHProxy]]`

   Then on SSHProxy : `ssh user@[[Server]] -L8443:iface2:443`
2. From [[MyStation]] : `ssh user@[[SSHProxy]] -L8443:127.0.0.1:8443`

I'm looking for a faster way...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Your question is frankly painful to read -- Please take a few minutes and rework it so the formatting is nicer and what you are asking is ore clearly stated. Full, complete, formal English sentences are encouraged. Take a look at some highly-voted questions and our [Markdown editing help](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) for some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config file could be something like

```
$ cat .ssh/config 
   Host Server
         HostName [[Server]]
         User [[Server_user]]
         LocalForward 8443 iface2:443
         ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p [[SSHProxy_user]]@[[SSHProxy]]
```